# How to feature only chosen subsubsections in the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc, etoc

I am working on a document which contains a lot of `section`s, `subsection`s, and `subsubsection`s. I am only printing the `section`s and `subsection`s in the table of contents to keep it less cluttered. However, I need to print some particular `subsubsection`s in the `toc`. How do I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large}{}{0pt}{\Large\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\centering}{}{0pt}{\bfseries}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section One}
    \subsection{Subsection A}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection a}
    \section{Section Two}
    \subsection{Subsection A}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection a}
    \subsection{Subsection B}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection a}% Want to print this subsubsection
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection b}% Want to print this subsubsection
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection c}
\end{document}
```

> **EDIT:** I realise that a naive way to achieve this is to change all the `\subsubsection`s to `\subsubsection*`s except the ones I want to
> appear in the `toc`. However, this will be a gruesome task given the
> length of the document. As a remedy, I tried adding the following
> lines into the preamble:
>
> ```
> \let\subsubsection\oldsubsubsection
> \renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\subsubsection*}
> %\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
> ```
>
> and then I called the particular subsubsections as `\oldsubsubsection`. But this trick also
> does not work. Please enlighten where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create infinite loop because the `\subsubsection*` is another form of the `\subsubsection`. The right way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large}{}{0pt}{\Large\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\centering}{}{0pt}{\bfseries}
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\oldsubsubsection*}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section One}
    \subsection{Subsection A}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection a}
    \section{Section Two}
    \subsection{Subsection A}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection a}
    \subsection{Subsection B}
    \oldsubsubsection{Subsubsection a}% Want to print this subsubsection
    \oldsubsubsection{Subsubsection b}% Want to print this subsubsection
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. Neat! Thanks.